# Cannot grant permission to edit Roll-up summary or formula fields

Tags: metadata-api, security

I am trying to give a profile edit access to a Formula field and Roll-up summary field, I did so with metadata like so:

```
<fieldPermissions>
    <editable>true</editable>
    <field>Account.SPC_Primary_Contact__c</field>
    <readable>true</readable>
</fieldPermissions>
```

the build completes but in the UI for that profile I see this:

[image]

I get it this is a formula field and Roll up summary so no would be able to edit these fields through the UI, they look the same for System Administrator, but a system admin can edit the configuration of the fields like this: 
[image]

... but the other profile does not see the edit button:

[image]

... Am I missing something ? How can I let this other profile edit these two fields ? I have granted edit access with the Metadata api but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permission to alter the *metadata* of fields is separate from permission to edit the *content* of the fields. The latter is controlled on a field-by-field basis by the Field-Level Security permissions architecture.

The former, ability to edit the definitions of fields, is granted on an org basis, not a per-field basis. The relevant permission is [Customize Application](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000194001&type=1&language=en_US), which also grants quite a bit of additional access across your org's configuration. It should typically be provided only to trusted administrators.